# How to correct middle coordinate between two coordinates

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, apple-maps

I have app that draw red line on the apple map while user drive car with iPhone.
But sometimes when driver drives too fast on corners I don't get all coordinates so it connects two points with straight line (and I get flying car :)).
Is there any solution how to make this more precise.
On the image I show what happens.
Large error on this image is at 'terminal ave and Clark...'
As user drive car I store each new coordinate in database (local) and based on that I draw route.
But this errors drive me creasy.
Any idea or example how to fix this error on corners.
[image]

Comment: i dont think you can do anything about this without having access to the street-data vectors.

Comment: I don't understand. No solution for this? What does it means 'access to street data vectors'? How some others applications that track user driving show correct paths? What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: I mean, you can not map your points to the way the driver was taking if you have no idea how the path should most likely look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do anything precise. The only thing you can do is to "guess" the route the driver got.

You can soft this "straight line effect" by some kind of interpolation between the two points which are too far away one from the other.

In video games industry, when an autonomous character is moving from one point to another, to avoid him just going straight forward steering Behaviors are used so he go in a soft and rounded way.

Maybe you read about them and see if u can apply them to your project.

[Steering behaviours](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/)